# Can't remove header in React Native Application

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, navigation

I'm new in building a react native app but I do have experience in android studio little bit, I'm using `Stack.Navigatior` for this but I've already hide the header by setting `headerShown: false`, When I've tried `headerShown: true` it will append another header so I just need to remain to false but the other one still exists, I just want to remove the header above, but how? need help for this

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { CryptoDetail, Transaction } from "./screens";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

import Tabs from "./navigation/tabs";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    SplashScreen.hide()
  },[])
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        initialRouteName={'Home'}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Tabs}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="CryptoDetail"
          component={CryptoDetail}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Transaction"
          component={Transaction}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none"> try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `headerShown: false` for every Navigator, not just one. Somewhere in your code, for example in the "Tabs" component, you have another Navigator and you need to set it there too.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have only one navigator in my app which allocates all my tabs and I think I've already applied `headerShown: false`  in that navigator

Comment: Thanks I found out that I have another navigator to my other files and put `headerShown: false` it works